# Restrict return type of TS function that returns union

Tags: typescript

I have written a util function that is used to parse API exceptions and return modeled TS types.

```js
interface NotFoundException {
  type: 'notFound'
}

interface PermissionException {
  type: 'permission'
}

interface BadRequestException {
  type: 'badRequest'
}

// Example shape of API Error 
interface APIError {
  statusCode: number;
}

type KnownExceptions = NotFoundException | PermissionException | BadRequestException;

function exceptionHandler(err: unknown): KnownExceptions {
  const statusCode = (err as APIError).statusCode ?? -1;

  if (statusCode === 404) {
    return {
      type: 'notFound'
    }
  }

  if (statusCode === 403) {
    return {
      type: 'permission'
    }
  }

  if (statusCode === 400) {
    return {
      type: 'badRequest'
    }
  }

  throw new Error('Unknown error', { cause: err });
}
```

Some APIs do not return all types, so I need to handle other types explicitly

```js
interface APIInput {
  prop: string;
}

interface APIOutput {
  id: string;
}

function callAPI(input: APIInput): APIOutput | PermissionException | NotFoundException {
  try {
    //Mock API call
    return {
      id: 'id'
    };
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    const e = exceptionHandler(err);

    // Problem: This API (and others) cannot throw this/some exceptions

    // Need a function that will restrict the types returned by exceptionHandler
    // and throw 'Unexpected exception' for impossible cases
    if (e.type === 'badRequest') {
      throw new Error('Unexpected exception', { cause: err });
    }

    return e;
  }
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHswDF0FcQAmAogB5IAOYw6IyA3gFDLJgCe5EAXMgOQiY58BHgwC%20DBqEixEKAArQAtsADOK6iFIUqNekxbsuvDlGVqNI8ZPDR4SZACE4BAEoQAjrggqwWiJQ09ZjYObh4AI2c3T28wSwkAegTkUjhFcgAbFBUACzgOZHQYZABBOQBJFKgodChka2k7FDLyomraoOQfODBcFQBhdAIjEFxFcOgAbjEJEJQAaX4Ad00yfx0QFWQAXjQBPEI-AN0AH2QFU1V1GiON5DOnVw8vH1uNaYYYfAQ7iDXjkAACTghCyUAAFNAoNx8ABrZYgACU3EW6BWbxoW0YzAQmLAXTAPT6g2GO2QkOqyDgWxabRqUERADpur0BkMUAB%20DnIAC0AEYPsxgMVwSzieydttdgAWAAM0sRnWYUAgvSgtGxzC1czC-GwB2E%20mY4mNEiFIrFbNJUplsoAzIrNcrVbh1UrtYYwiYzNcQCItcgTYGzchheTLSSUDbkHLZY6jcgVWqNQngp7eJEnjEfP6tUGrMEcjUlsgQBAS3TauCeABVEDwtG0KG1HgAGnoyAQcD6RihgcR0ysSV5PNHY55CFwYDHEiktlkpQq5RA5CnnXINXI3B8UFAAHNB7ObDJ7C0APJT1f4zXAAjbsC7kAHmafb53LsZDItcGgK-cFrLleyKLuUF5gFe9znEoVwaBitBnBg%20pCHBnQPqw7pJAAsugCCwiBnZwJ%20CZJq6KYBkKd68LeubGtMxoEWACA5OSUIwvWCLxgGuKbPiUbIH82gaMCoLQBSDKClqw5yDU4RZIo3AACo5Ko%20HgiCBCFGAOTQCoipdiAeosEWaJGaoCQqOgigoAJ6waCoIbMMOqAQBAGlwMgXwgD8gRaT0yBLMAn6JrEu4-EZKBzFsJHqq5yDhOhNkAsJBBggmw7qUZxa8HWfwcD8sWJRsPAeR0wDpOg5iySgXYqN4CZhpCjJzJKuwRFEzyxDwnHkVpWVlhW7QQrWZYkHlkAaYVFjtnQBE9twfaiAOCYFlq0VNnRwaiEAA)

Is there a way I can write a function that restricts the return types of the union of exceptions to what I want and throw an `Unexpected exception` error for all other types ?

Since TS cannot take types as arguments I'm finding it hard to figure this out.

Comment: Please [edit] this code to be a [mre] without typos or pseudocode or private/undeclared types or values. Ideally we can paste it into our IDEs and immediately get to work without first resolving problems you're asking about.  You should try it in an IDE yourself and fix anything unrelated (e.g., `types`? `"badRequestException"`? a second argument to `new Error()` that isn't an options object? etc etc)  When you're done hopefully the problem you're having jumps out at us; [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/NdJPdW) is mostly just typo fixes but I don't see the problem. What's the issue?

Comment: @jcalz Done. Basically I'd like a way to restrict the return type of the exceptionHandler per API so I don't need to handle impossible cases (they all throw an exception anyway)

Comment: Where is that information represented? How do I (and by extension, TypeScript) know what exceptions an API can or cannot make?

Comment: It's part of the API documentation, nothing in code sadly

Comment: Well then at best you'd have to translate that info to some types in your typescript code and then write something to consume that.  Which I'm thinking the existing answer is showing you so I guess I have nothing amazing to add here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
type ApiType = 'foo' | 'bar';

type AllowedExceptionsByApiType = {
    foo: PermissionException | NotFoundException,
    bar: BadRequestException
}

function exceptionHandler<T extends ApiType>(apiType: T, error: unknown): AllowedExceptionsByApiType[T] {
    // impl
}
```

We declare possible api types in `ApiType`, then possible exception by each api type in `AllowedExceptionsByApiType`.

Then, using generics, the return type of `exceptionHandler` is constrained to those exception allowed by the api type.

---

**Example:**

```
function callApi(input: SomeInput): Output | PermissionException | NotFoundException {
    try {
        //API Call
    } catch (err: unknown) {
        const e = exceptionHandler('foo', err);

        // error
        if (e.type === 'badRequestException') {
            throw new Error('Unexpected exception', err);
        }

        // ok
        if (e.type === 'notFound') {
            // impl
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks interesting, I'll give it a go, Im a bit miffed that I'll have to store the config globally somewhere, we have a few hundred APIs, but this broadly works

Answer (score 1):

As you pointed out, specifying your possible exceptions (for a given API) only as TS types is not enough, because you need them at runtime to filter out the other exceptions.

Therefore, there will necessarily be a place where you store this information. In Murolem's answer, it is stored in 2 places:

- a centralized type-only mapping of API kind to possible exceptions
- within the `catch` block of each of your API call, where you have to manually handle non expected types

Another possible architecture could contain all this information solely in the `catch` block, and leverage TypeScript inference to correctly type the `callAPI` return automatically:

```
// TS correctly infers the possible returned exceptions
function callAPI(input: APIInput) {
  //     ^? APIOutput | PermissionException | NotFoundException
  try {
    // Mock API call
    return {
      id: 'id'
    } as APIOutput;
  } catch (err: unknown) {
    // Turn err into a Known Exception only if its type is one of the specified values.
    return restrictExceptionsTo(err, "permission", "notFound");
  }
}

/**
 * Convert the given error into a Known Exception,
 * but only those of given possible types;
 * otherwise throw an unexpected exception.
 */
function restrictExceptionsTo<T extends KnownExceptionsTypes>(err: unknown, ...possibleTypes: T[]) {
  const e = exceptionHandler(err);

  // Throw if the built exception is of not expected type
  if (!isExceptionOfType(e, ...possibleTypes)) {
    throw new Error('Unexpected exception', { cause: err });
  }

  // The remaining exception is only of expected type
  return e;
}
```

This relies on a custom Type Guard and a few helper types to tell TypeScript how to infer the expected types:

```
/** Union of known exceptions types key */
type KnownExceptionsTypes = KnownExceptions["type"]
//   ^? "notFound" | "permission" | "badRequest"

/** Exclude from KnownExceptions union the types which "type" key do not match T */
type PossibleExceptions<T extends KnownExceptionsTypes, KE = KnownExceptions> =
  // Distributive conditional type union trick
  KE extends KnownExceptions
  ? KE["type"] extends T ? KE : never
  : never;

/** Example usage */
type OnlyBadRequest = PossibleExceptions<"badRequest">;
//   ^? BadRequestException is automatically inferred

/**
 * Type Guard to check that the given exception has a "type" key
 * which matches one of the given possible "type" values.
 */
function isExceptionOfType<T extends KnownExceptionsTypes>(e: KnownExceptions, ...possibleTypes: T[]): e is PossibleExceptions<T> {
  return possibleTypes.includes(e.type as T); // e.type may be different from the possible types, that is the point of this Type Guard!
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHswDF0FcQAmAogB5IAOYw6IyA3gFDLJgCe5EAXMgOQiY58BHgwC+DBqEixEKAArQAtsADOK6iFIUqNekxbsuvDlGVqNI8ZPDR4SZACE4BAEoQAjrggqwWiJQ09ZjYObh4AI2c3T28wSwkAegTkUjhFcgAbFBUACzgOZHQYZABBOQBJFKgodChka2k7FDLyomraoOQfODBcFQBhdAIjEFxFcOgAbjEJEJQAaX4Ad00yfx0QFWQAXjQBPEI-AN0AH2QFU1V1GiON5DOnVw8vH1uNaYYYfAQ7iDXjkAACTghCyUAAFNAoNx8ABrZYgACU3EW6BWbxoW0YzAQmLAXTAPT6g2GO2QkOqyDgWxabRqUERADpur0BkMUAB+DnIAC0AEYPsxgMVwSzieydttdgAWAAM0sRnWYUAgvSgtGxzC1czC-GwB2E+mY4mNEiFIrFbNJUplsoAzIrNcrVbh1UrtYYwiYzNcQCItcgTYGzchheTLSSUDbkHLZY6jcgVWqNQngp7eJEnjEfP6tUGrMEcjUlsgQBAS3TauCeABVEDwtG0KG1HgAGnoyAQcD6RihgcR0ysSV5PNHY55CFwYDHEiktlkpQq5RA5CnnXINXI3B8UFAAHNB7ObDJ7C0APJT1f4zXAAjbsC7kAHmYMYcAFQAyp3aiqfhlWKGIAwNAWxgDkKDkOg5jhFkiYuuqEAEMgfzaBoKifN8dxdhkGQtOCoBXtwLTLleiIJAAVERFQXmAV73OcShXBoGK0GcGD6kILHkckmrDgGAB6HL6A+AFOsgw4ALLoAgsKLpU2EZAmSauimAZCnevC3rmxpUjS1GXlO0w6V2YAIDk5JQjC9YIvGAbvipyGUlI6BUsgqIrCk-x3DQ-6hsUwBgKBhihlsNAoEULDgV0HAIMKwCIcgABucAZC8jJKfBtAqjuwA-CxKhvugFJQO2ABE3pMTQpVlXqgiEKVA76OIQ7keRyB1oEEUNh5KHrGhBgcFssIQAB3EMHMbkIvlb6GFsuzuasqGYgA2qVcylQAuq+yTMIJiStUwbWDCAiXQPiYEoHuwCnU27R1M5rkLZ5S0gK2h3IOEa4+QBYFQeFxRXTdyCQdBsFzCoRltZg4FQEsqgoGBxZUrQ+B-DFkBIb1ALpcgY1fCAPyBNlD65b4XloYVAA8b7ISQkCEFsC3TbNAB8xVWd1r3IIyPMg+oMEQDNg3cG+y0bbZ4k7Vqe04niyFkljGzAqC0DFY1+jvkWaJ+ZFKCfcAGT4orgSqIUxR6rT6MJXM+hhuCACEqgsWeMBCxAkLtjzjJ88AAtuyoiIS4WSNlhWd3VnWaMQD8CXGzQbYdl2PbcH2oiNaaGvJG+UUqoocCgPutMvSFhQgL5EVRzHSE286ybIUZktqXtLVtVoqWkjANSKJNjb5cg+CBBdA3eMgSw5Ll5lrYYpXIMNAEEC5Ft56Z5k02NE1yFB-NZPl1O0-TBCM1N5OYv77bzEQZJMyfmwszsmfIAAIqoJOfVQp3foQAUaClw-9yAg9dwyX0BffeEAGY93RDfdCzBuQX1WutDaYCIE0zgZfbgZZTpQH0BgiAWCPgUVbiQNImQUB9DgHuFA69gpnjLqwR40QXj4l2JvUGEBd6lUzIw2IpUWbTD4sgPar4Dq42QG7ZAABxXAcAoDVxcmZaOskwI9F1sgQG4Ci59V0HkLYcBkBTw4DPOe70x4T2QMvBRoUyxm1Ueo2gPsBb6PWklFKaVDoJAwgTO4Tsb4uzdnvP4B8j692gf7NmRhr4vRUJ7XmW9fZZH9iLMWyJ5am1Ydvdh0DqZ301MpN0DiEmzUZKABA7dvCQkZBNakYiByNwgJU4KecAITGQAQYUwEVTgGQJ3dA3ch4FIRrNdsyj8Sm36egKQNiwKm3EVImRBB7YzCAA)